# Excessive inter-word spacing when parsing XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I am parsing XML using NSXMLParser. Everything works good except one XML tag:

```
<place>USA , Boston</place>
```

when I parse this tag, the value is

```
USA               ,               Boston
```

Somehow spaces are added between words. Any ideas why it is happening and how can I fix it?

**UPDATED**
The code I am using is straightforward. The string that I receive in  `parser:foundCharacters:` delegate call is already with spaces. I am using:

```
[_currentString appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```

to remove spaces and new lines, but it is only for the beginning and the end of the string.

Comment: Can you change the `XML` format ?

Comment: Can you please add the Parsing code ?

Answer (score 1):

- In FoundCharacters method we have to replace these special character.

> string =[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t"
>   withString:@""];
>
> ```
> [_currentString appendString:string];
> ```

Comment: Then Use string =[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

Answer (score 0):

Will be good if you show you `code` of in short if you can edit the `XML` format than one solution will be you can add the tag value between `CDATA` like

```
<place><![CDATA[USA , Boston]]></place>
```

CDATA section is a section of element content that is marked for the parser to interpret as only character data

Comment: show your code used for parsing or you can remove `whitespaces` if you want.